# what's the best way to make this layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know, what's the best way to make this layout using HTML and CSS only.

[image: layout]

Header and Footer cover 100% width of the window. Container has max-width of 1200px. Sidenav needs to have different background colour - Sidenav content sits inside the container but the background should extend to the left of the window.

- Sidenav width should be 30% of the container
- Main width should be 70% of the container

Here is what I've got so far:

```
<header>
..
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ccol-lg-3 sidenav">
      <!-- Side nav -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" >
      <!-- Main -->
    </div>
  </div>   
</div>
<footer>
...
</footer>
```

I'm using flexbox grid...

I've also tried to to move  outside the container but the problem is then on resize it sidenav doesn't align with header and footer "containers"...

I created a quick mockup to demonstrate my problem: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOVZYY

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't really intended as a "do it for me" site. What HTML/ CSS do you have now and in what way is it not working? If you're looking for "the best" way, [SO isn't the place to ask](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286557/is-it-okay-to-ask-code-optimization-help)  - [there's a separate site for code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @DACrosby please see [a guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788). Code Review requires code that's already implemented, and working as intended.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks, I've updated my question and provided more information

Comment: @DACrosby I'd appreciate if you could remove your downvote. Happy to provide more information if it's required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the width of the side nav you could do:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  /* side margin on the container so its centered */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* side nav width so that content and nav don't mix */
  padding-left: 30%;
  /* keeps the padding from making the container larger than the set width */
  box-sizing border-box;
}
.side-nav {
  /* side nav width */
  width: 30%;
  /* position absolute fixes the side nav to the side */
  position: absolute;
  /* set the position, its relative to the container because of the containers position relative */
  top: 0;
  left: 30%;
}
.side-nav:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
}
```

This should do what you want if you replace the length values with your own. You can also use percent (%) and viewport relative (vw, vh, vmin, vmax) values.

Here is an example: http://codepen.io/CKH4/pen/yOVZGb, it should meet all the requirements you suggested. If you want the side-nav to float set:

```
.main {
  overflow: auto;
}
```